# using umask to set default file settings

Tags: linux, umask

I am setting default umask of linux box for the first time.  I log in as root user on a Centos 6 server. I want these default values:

```
owner:  read/execute/write (7)
group:  read/execute (5)
other:  read (4)
```

To get umask value, I deduct targets from 777: 777-754 = 023

```
# umask 023
```

then do a double check

```
# umask -S
  u=rwx,g=rx,o=r
```

then create and display file permissions

```
# echo x > testfile.txt
# ll | grep testfile.txt
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root   root           4 Jun 26 01:15 testfile.txt
```

which is not quite what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`umask` filters the permissions requested by the application which is commonly `666` for regular files.

Because shells will not set file execute bit by default, as a security precaution, you always have to set it manually when required.

Comment: thanks for answer!!  I read this elsewhere but I did not see link to my problem.